# Pandas: groupby and assign all other rows a value from a single specific row and column

Tags: python, pandas

How might I get the value for each `Key`, given that `Type` is equal to `B` and assign that result to every `A`? I need to apply this logic to a large dataframe with many different groups.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Group': ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],
                   'Type': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
                   'Flag': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
                   })
```

Expected outcome:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         'Group': ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],
                   'Type': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A',],
                   'parentKey': [3, 3, np.nan, 3, 3],
                   'Flag': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]})
```

I have been playing with `transform` but am rather stumped and not getting anywhere close.

Comment: Is there only one row with type 'B'?  What happens if there are many rows with type 'B'?

Comment: Many rows with type `B`!

Comment: So the types are only a/b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to do a merge:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Group': ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],
                   'Type': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
                   'Flag': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
                   })
df_parent = df.loc[df['Type'] == 'B', ['Key', "Group"]].rename(columns={'Key':'parentKey'})
pd.concat([df[df['Type'] != 'B'].merge(df_parent, on = 'Group', how = 'left'), df.loc[df['Type'] == 'B']], ignore_index=True)
```

```
    Key Group   Type    Flag    parentKey
0   1   Z       A       0       3.0
1   2   Z       A       0       3.0
2   4   Z       A       0       3.0
3   5   Z       A       0       3.0
4   3   Z       B       1       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, the merge intuition is great.